# Can i refer entire section from values file in the helm template?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have my values.yaml as below

```
account:
  - name: abc
    value: value1
  - name: xyz
    value: value2
```

i want to refer them in my helm template. instead of referring them as

```
accounts:
  - name: acount1
    value: "{{ .Values.account.abc }}"
  - name: account2
    value: "{{ .Values.account.xyz }}"
```

is there a way i can refer entire block in my template as

```
accounts:
      {{ .Values.account }}
```

and it will iterate through all the values passed in the values.yaml file ?

Answer (score 7):

Helm has a minimally-documented `toYaml` function that will write an arbitrary structure as YAML.  You will also need it indented to be under `accounts:` in the output structure, and the [sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/strings.html) `indent` or `nindent` functions can help with this.

```
accounts: {{- .Values.account | toYaml | trim | nindent 2 }}
```

Comment: Thanks David. I did tried ```accounts: {{ toYaml .Values.account | nindent 2 }}```  But getting  ```did not find expected key```  error.

Answer (score 0):

Could able to figure it out. This worked.

```
accounts:
   {{- range $account := .Values.account }}
   - name: {{ $account.name }}
     value: {{ $account.value | quote }}
   {{- end }}
```